# Site/DNS with subdomain to any private IP addresses?

Tags: dns

So several years ago I saw a DNS service which you could for example put something like: `192.168.1.2.<something>.io` and it would return an A record for 192.168.1.2.

You could put any IP address as the subdomain and it would return the A Record for that IP address.

This was useful for testing website configuration  on a private network when you couldn't edit the company DNS records.

Sadly I cannot remember the name of the site. I think it was a `.io` domain, but that is all I remember.

**Does anyone know the name of this service, or a tool that could do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess you're referring to [xip.io](http://xip.io). I'm not sure what more meaningful information I can add here, though.

I read about this first in the "Ansible: Up and Running" book and have never used it myself, but it's still available as of today, as a cursory check proves.